# Transposing 2 Cell Rows into 2 Cell Columns Quickly

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

[image: Before-After Picture]

I have been trying to quickly push two cells into subsequent columns.  I tried transpose shortcuts, Text to Columns, and other coding, but the fastest way is Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V over and over again.

Does anyone have a quick/simple solution?

Comment: I would try to script something in VBA.

Comment: [Sample data as an image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) is generally discouraged but those hand drawn arrows are to die for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick formula:

(Note this will not delete the existing but merely copy over the values.)

Put this in column B next to the first name and copy over one column and down:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,4)=0,INDEX($A:$A,ROW()+COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Answer (score 3):

Some quick VBA would look like this,

```
dim rw as long
with activesheet
    for rw=315 to .cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row step 4
        .cells(rw, "A").offset(-1, 1).resize(1, 2) = application.transpose(.cells(rw, "A").resize(2, 1)).value
        .cells(rw, "A").resize(2, 1).clearcontents
    next rw
end with
```

Step through a few loops with [F8] and when you are happy with it, put the cursor on `End With` and tap [ctrl]+[F8].

Comment: I have yet to learn VBA functionality. I'm very basic right now.  The IF statement helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Kutools** for performing operations such as Transposing a range in case you are not aware of formulas .